# Обработка ошибки PDO в php

Tags: ооп, php_pdo, php, warning, mysql

Так подключаюсь к базе, и хочу проверить соединение...

```
try{
      $this->DataBaseLink = new PDO($Patern,$this->_user,$this->_password);
   }
catch (PDOException $e)
   {
      echo 'no connect';
   }
```

вместо просто надписи "нет подключения" выводится и Warning:

> PDO::__construct() [<a
> href='pdo.--construct'>pdo.--construct</a>]:
> [2002] Попытка установить соединение
> была безуспешной, т.к. от другого
> компьютера за требуемое время не
> получен нужный отклик

Как убрать ворнинг?... отключить в апаче не вариант...

Comment: Просто исправить эту ошибку не получается?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
try {
$PDO = new PDO( '...' ); // PDO Driver DSN. Throws A PDOException.
}
catch( PDOException $Exception ) {
    // PHP Fatal Error. Second Argument Has To Be An Integer, But PDOException::getCode Returns A
    // String.
    throw new MyDatabaseException( $Exception->getMessage( ) , $Exception->getCode( ) );
}
```

По моему в документации хорошо описано)